# Parsing data from Java to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html

Below here is my HTML code, JavaClient and JavaServer code. I obtained user input from the client program and send it to the server program. Then, I would like to modify the user input and parse it into the javascript in my HTML code, which is from receive & receive1 in server to lati & longi in HTML.

Question: May i know is it possible for me to parse the data from my java server to my HTML page?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="latitude"></p>
<p id="longtitude"></p>

<script>
var lati = 1;
var longti = 20;
document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML = lati;
document.getElementById("longtitude").innerHTML = longti;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Java UDPBaseServer code:

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.net.DatagramPacket; 
import java.net.DatagramSocket; 
import java.net.InetAddress; 
import java.net.SocketException; 
  
public class Server 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    { 
        // Step 1 : Create a socket to listen at port 1234 
        DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(1234); 
        byte[] receive = new byte[65535]; 
        byte[] receive1 = new byte[65535];
  
        DatagramPacket DpReceive = null; 
        DatagramPacket DpReceive1 = null; 
        while (true) 
        { 
  
            // Step 2 : create a DatgramPacket to receive the data. 
            DpReceive = new DatagramPacket(receive, receive.length); 
            DpReceive1 = new DatagramPacket(receive1, receive1.length); 
  
            // Step 3 : receive the data in byte buffer. 
            ds.receive(DpReceive); 
            ds.receive(DpReceive1);
  
            System.out.println("Latitude:-" + data(receive)); 
            System.out.println("Longtitude:-" + data(receive1)); 
  
            // Exit the server if the client sends "bye" 
            if (data(receive).toString().equals("bye")) 
            { 
                System.out.println("Client sent bye.....EXITING"); 
                break; 
            } 
  
            // Clear the buffer after every message. 
            receive = new byte[65535]; 
        } 
    } 
  
    // A utility method to convert the byte array 
    // data into a string representation. 
    public static StringBuilder data(byte[] a) 
    { 
        if (a == null) 
            return null; 
        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder(); 
        int i = 0; 
        while (a[i] != 0) 
        { 
            ret.append((char) a[i]); 
            i++; 
        } 
        return ret; 
    } 
}
```

Java UDPBaseClient code:

```
//Java program to illustrate Client side 
//Implementation using DatagramSocket 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.net.DatagramPacket; 
import java.net.DatagramSocket; 
import java.net.InetAddress; 
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Client 
{ 
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
 { 
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

     // Step 1:Create the socket object for 
     // carrying the data. 
     DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(); 
     DatagramSocket ds1 = new DatagramSocket();

     InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); 
     byte buf[] = null; 
     byte buf1[] = null;

     // loop while user not enters "bye" 
     while (true) 
     { 
         System.out.println("Latitude:");
         String inp = sc.nextLine(); 
         System.out.println("Longtitude:");
         String inp1 = sc.nextLine();

         // convert the String input into the byte array. 
         buf = inp.getBytes(); 
         buf1 = inp1.getBytes(); 

         // Step 2 : Create the datagramPacket for sending 
         // the data. 
         DatagramPacket DpSend = 
               new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, ip, 1234); 
         DatagramPacket DpSend1 = 
                 new DatagramPacket(buf1, buf1.length, ip, 1234); 

         // Step 3 : invoke the send call to actually send 
         // the data. 
         ds.send(DpSend); 
         ds1.send(DpSend1);

         // break the loop if user enters "bye" 
         if (inp.equals("bye")) 
             break; 
     } 
 } 
}
```

Comment: are you doing socket programming and the html page is the client side?

Comment: i have a udpbaseclient java program that take user input and send it to my udpbaseserver. After that, i want the data from udpbaseserver to be parsed into my html page.

Comment: @Jason Javascript does not support socket programming( expect flash,  which is not supported by major browsers in the near future), you should provide a http rest API for your HTML page to fetch the data.

Comment: @QiuZhou may i know is there any way for me to receive data from my server? This is because i want to obtain the coordinates and plot on the google map using Google Map API

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your really sense in your case.
if that's a web app, you can startup an WebServer e.g Tomcat on server-side, and you can obtained the Java output with fetch in the JavaScript in Browser.

if you wanna just simple run it on file protocol in Browser, the Java need to writing a JavaScript file with the Output, like below case

data.js

```js
var data = JSON.parse('<YOUR JAVA OUTPUT JSON STRINGT>');
```

html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="latitude"></p>
<p id="longtitude"></p>
<script src="data.js"></script>
<script>
var lati = 1;
var longti = 20;
document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML = data.lati;
document.getElementById("longtitude").innerHTML = data.longti;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: may i know how can I do this in Java? e.g creating a connection to parse the data

Comment: @Jason Avoid we on the wrong way, so you could tell about your sense detail, How do you want to running on right now?

Comment: I want to take the coordinates from the server and plot it on Google map API

Comment: @Jason in your case, where to show Google map? Desktop App? Web App? or Mobile App?

Comment: I am showing my google map using pc browser